# How to debug remote Glassfish web app from Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, glassfish

The web app I'm trying to debug only exhibits a bug on a particular Glassfish server, so I want to debug the web app remotely. But the web app was developed in Eclipse for Java SE and I can't see how to do that.

I have:

1. Installed Eclipse 3.7 for Java EE
2. Installed the Glassfish adapter
3. Configured the server for secure login and JPDA debugging
4. Added the server as a server in Eclipse

However, I do not see "Run on server" or "Debug on server" in the Run menu of Eclipse. If do Debug as, I can create a new Glassfish configuration but I can't select a server, so I can't configure the configuration.

Comment: It seems that the Glassfish adapter for Eclipse is quite buggy.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For Glassfish 3:

First enable debugging in the Glassfish administration console 
(Application Server -> JVM Settings -> General -> Debug Options)
which require restarting the domain.  Make a note of the port number.

Then you can attach to the Glassfish debug port like any other debug session, with a "Remote Java Application" in the debug configurations.

Comment: I tried that, but on Glassfish v2.1 I still had to `asadmin start-domain --debug domain1` to get it to listen on the debug port.

Comment: Apparently this was changed for Glassfish 3.